# Disabling Password Login for Root User via PAM on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ssh, pam, ubuntu-22.04

I have a Ubuntu Server (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1049-oracle aarch64) specfically), Where I am hosting a few projects, I am somewhat novice in the sysadmin space, but know some basics for setting up `sshd` to be more secure. Now, I know `root` bad. I have gone to some decent lengths to keep things secure.

In the server, I have:

- changed the port in which `SSHd` is listening
- Set up authentication via SSH Keys
- Set up and enabled `libpam-google-authenticator` and made it manditory, for all users, including `root`, using [this guide from ubuntu/canonical](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa#1-overview)
- Set the following options in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
MaxAuthTries 6
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
```

- Per the setup for the same 2FA guide, changes to PAM (`/etc/pam.d/sshd`):

```
# Standard Un*x authentication. Comment to disable normal passwd handling
#@include common-auth

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
auth required pam_permit.so
```

Now, where I am worried, is normally, I'd elect for `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`, but as it turns out, for it to handle `keyboard-interactive`, it has to be yes ([please reference this ServerFault post from several years ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/869627/google-authenticator-pam-on-ssh-blocks-root-login-without-2fa)).

Now the problem. I obviously don't want to allow passwd auth via SSH for `root` at all, but I do want to have `root` accessible via SSH; using `privatekey`(secured with a passphrase) & 2FA via `google-authenticator`. I may go back in and set it in `sshd_config` later that such logins are on another port, and from only X IP address, but I digress. This should, in theory, be plenty secure for my little project server.

In this case, to ensure that passwd is not an approved method without changing the relevant `sshd_config` line, is there a method via PAM to specify for a specified user, Password is denied?
Or, Does this still get covered under `PasswordAuthentication no`, encompassing `root`?
Is this handled by commenting out `@include common-auth` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`?

Or, simply, what would be the best way of ensuring passwd auth for `root` is denied where `PermitRootLogin` is `yes` and that cannot change, to ensure a (reasonably) secure ssh instance where external root login is permitted?

I tried usual google-fu of checking for similar questions, similar setups, or methods of configuring PAM to deny passwd for a single user. Similar info was from 2017, and thus commenting to inquire about the subject would be necroing very hard. (I also posted this on StackOverflow for it to get deleted, From what I can tell this is the closest place for this kind of question)

Comment: Why do you need root login at all? By default it is disabled on Ubuntu. Log in as a regular user and elevate using sudo.

Comment: or if using sudo is annoying, `su - root` is also possible